# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, maven, classpath, apache-poi, noclassdeffounderror

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook
```

This is java web project. The java project is ok, but in web, I got this exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
```

maven dependency :

```
<!-- apahce poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Are the Apache POI jars available in your war (WEB-INF/lib)?

Answer (score 5):

You need to put the Apache POI files in the WEB-INF/lib folder on the server.

Comment: Using maven add dependency, and all of libs is available in maven library. build a war, and publish to tomcat, it's ok. but ...

Comment: @Mathias Schwarz The jars are already there in the mentioned location at the time of build these are getting packed and I can see these are available. So what could be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Check `.m2` directory and try to find class `HSSFWorkbook` if this class is present, check lib folder of your web app and try to find the same.

Comment: I'm using Maven and this jar file is present in classpath already. Now how to fixed this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```